# Accessing translations provider in Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to access translations used in Angular2 bootstrap:

```
getTranslationProviders()
  .then(providers => {
    return platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, providers);
  })
```

Where `providers` is the array:

```
[
    {provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: translations},
    {provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf'},
    {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: locale}
]
```

I see the translations being used in the app, but when I try to use them myself, for example

```
class TranslationsService {
  constructor(@Inject(TRANSLATIONS) translations) {...}
}
```

I get an error saying `No provider for Token Translations!`

I've also tried making another provider with the token MY_TRANSLATIONS and add to the list of providers, thinking that angular might invalidate TRANSLATIONS during bootstrap somehow, but it didn't work either.

How can I access the translations? Why I can't access them even though I provide them in bootstrap.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: @s3m3n yes, but it was a long time ago so I don't remember the details. This gist is that I processed the translations file myself.